# goimports not working with the vim-go plugin

Tags: go, vim, vim-plugin

I followed the installation instructions here https://github.com/fatih/vim-go and ran `goimports hello.go`. The output was my code with the imported package but when I opened hello.go the file did not have the code for the imported package.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
goimports -w=true hello.go
```

to rewrite source instead of output to stdout

Comment: thanks alot. Is there a permanent solution to this? Or where is this documented?

Comment: in your `init.vim` add the line `let g:go_fmt_command = "goimports"`, assuming you're using `vim-go` plugin. This will auto import whenever you writ the file.

Answer (score 2):

Open the following go source file with your vim.

```
package main

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.ToUpper("hello"))
}
```

Then run `GoImports` in vim command line, the file should be updated to:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.ToUpper("gopher"))
}
```

I am using mvim 8.0.1420 on macOS 10.13.2. And vim-go version is `d2b0a234ffb5441a3488c78fe8e5f551ddbdd454`.